# LIMIT 1 with CrudRepository

Tags: java, mysql, spring, limit, crud

I would like to have one result of `MyTable` only the last inserted.
SO I put `LIMIT 1` or `LIMIT 0,1` but I have two results instead.
It throws an exception.
How can I do?
I use `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository` on mysql DB

```
    @Query("select t from  MyTable t " +
        " where " +
        "  t.date <= :date " +
        " order by t.date desc " +
        " LIMIT 1  ")   
 MyTable findOnlyTheLast(
        @Param("date") String date);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a conditional in the where clause that selects the max of dates meeting the criteria.

```
@Query("select t from  MyTable t " +
        " where " +
        "  t.date <= :date " +
        " and t.date = (select max(tt.date) from MyTable tt where tt.date <= :date)" +
        " order by t.date desc")
```